# Forcing 'git push' to Flush Out Logging Details

Tags: python, git

Is there a way to force `git push` to immediately flush its command line output?

For example, I have a large number of server side hooks and these take a fair amount of time to run.

Hence, git users often get stuck with the output below:

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 258 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

It is hard for them to determine whether something has gone wrong or if the hooks are merely taking longer than expected.

After waiting some time, the remaining output regarding post-receive tests are outputted to the command line.

Is there a way to produce continuous output such that each

`remote: [INFO]..`

is flushed to the command line immediately after each step has been finished instead of one big text of output at the end?

I have also tried `git push --verbose` but this does not appear to make a difference.

EDIT: I am also open to wrapping `git push` in a custom Python script if that is what it takes to get this to behave friendlier.

Comment: Are you sure your scripts for your hooks just aren't outputting until the very end? I use `post-receive` hooks and I see the output as it is generated.

Comment: Do the hooks need to run synchronously with the hook?